# node fetch returns only one data

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I took this url from instagram, it returns hashtags data. The parameters have to be passed as it is in the url, otherwise it won't show. When access, it shows several, but when consuming the url, it shows only one result

url: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/jeep/?__a=1

```
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const router = express.Router();




router.use('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  
  fetch("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/jeep/?__a=1")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))

  res.end()
})



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: it only shows one hashtag result? what does the console.log look like?

Comment: also, if you're in an async function, no need for then-chaining, just `await` things. (e.g. `const response = await fetch(url); const data = await response.json(); console.log(data);` - fun fact: the json() function does not _return_ json, it _parses_ json. It returns a plain JS object)